# Question made CW and still adding rep

Tags: support, community-wiki

[This question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/92984/how-do-i-ease-into-programming-coming-from-a-designer-background) was made CW (I'm not sure why - the whole CW criteria is pretty difficult to understand now) yet I am still getting rep accumulated when up-voted. My understanding is that rep is not affected by CW questions/answers. Has this changed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You got the last vote 8 hours ago at 6:05 UTC.

The question and all existing answers were made community Wiki 7 hours ago at 06:37 UTC when Mikey added an answer that took the total number answers over 15. Once a question has more than 15 answers it's converted to CW (the same as Super User, but 1/2 the value on Stack Overflow).

Therefore the answer wasn't CW when you earned the rep.

If I voted now you wouldn't get any rep.

Comment: Thank you, sir.